# XML-XSL using for loop

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT. I have a requirement where I need to convert an XML file to XSLT. In that, I need to iterate in a loop to get all the values from an XML like

```
<books>
<book-00>
<science price=""/>
.
.
.
<\book-00>
<book-01>
<english price=""/>
.
.
.

.
<\book-01>
<book-nn>
<\book-nn>
<\books>
```

How can I write a for loop with the dynamic count by reading it from an XML node into XSLT?

Comment: Who defined tags like `<book-01>`? if it not too late try to redefine those tags to `<book index="01">`, etc. so that you can handle them via `<template match="book">` construct.

Comment: A lot of missing significant information: 1. What is the exact output that must be produced. 2. What is meant by "a for loop with the dynamic count by reading it from a xml node in xslt"? Please, edit your question and provide the missing data so that it would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You try to avoid looping with XSLT, opting instead to use [templates](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XSLT_1.html).

You need to apply an XSLT stylesheet to your XML in order to produce some sort of output (normally a different XML dialect, such as XHTML).

How this is done depends on the language and platform you are using - however, you have not indicated which ones you are using.

I suggest reading up on XSLT before you continue.